# M1 Macbook crashing when Jupyter Kernel interrupted

Tags: macos, multiprocessing, jupyter, apple-m1

I am using the M1 Macbook Pro. I have noticed this problem while using jupyter and multiprocessing library together. Not sure the problem is specific to this combination, but that combination is where I experienced it multiple times. Every time I interrupt a kernel while multiprocessing.Pool.map is running my computer freezes, then crashes, and restarts.

Does anyone know why this happens or if there is a fix?

Comment: This sounds like something that's more appropriate as a bug report.